How to add section number in Beamer miniframes?
I like miniframes in Beamer presentations, so I often use smoothbars outer theme.
However, I would like to customize the miniframe Beamer style such that:

there is no section name and subsection name in the head (done via [subsection=false] and \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{}.)
But I would like to add the number of the section at the beginning of the bullet points (ie. miniframe) pack.
I would like also to add symbols for subsection (let's say x).

The final result (for the MWE below) should look like:
1 o o      2 x o o o x o o

The first constrain is easy to accomplish, but I don't know how to do the second one.
So my questions are: how to add the section number at the beginning of miniframe section pack? and how to do the same for subsection with another symbol ?
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}

   %% Remove sections names in the head.
   \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{}

   %% Unsuccessful attempt to add the section number at the beginning of a miniframe pack.
   \renewcommand{\sectionentry}[5]{
      \def\insertsectionheadnumber{#1}\hfill
   }


\begin{document}

\section{toto}
   \begin{frame}{toto}
      toto 1
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}{toto}
      toto 2
   \end{frame}

\section{tata}
\subsection{tutu}
   \begin{frame}{tutu}
        tutu
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}{tutu}
        tutu 2
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}{tutu}
        tutu 3
   \end{frame}

\subsection{titi}
    \begin{frame}{titi}
        titi
    \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}{titi}
        titi 1
    \end{frame}

\end{document}


Please don't mix different questions in a single post.

Quick hack to smuggle in the section number:
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}

%% Remove sections names in the head.
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{}

\makeatletter
\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
  \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#1>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
      \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \else%
      \ifnum#2=0%
        \beamer@ypos@offset=1\relax%
      \fi
      \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
      \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
      \advance\beamer@ypos by \beamer@ypos@offset\relax
    \fi%
  \hbox to 0pt{%
    \beamer@tempdim=-\beamer@vboxoffset%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by-\beamer@boxsize%
    \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@ypos%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm%
    \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3
      \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}}% <- change here
    \fi
    \raise\beamer@tempdim\hbox{%
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@boxsize%
      \multiply\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@xpos%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by -\beamer@boxsize%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 1pt%
      \kern\beamer@tempdim
      \global\beamer@section@min@dim\beamer@tempdim
      \hbox{\beamer@link(#4){%
          \usebeamerfont{mini frame}%
          \ifnum\c@section=#1%
            \ifnum\c@subsection=#2%
              \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
              \ifnum\c@subsectionslide=#3%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%\beamer@minislidehilight%
              \else%
                \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current subsection}%\beamer@minisliderowhilight%
              \fi%
            \else%
              \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
              %\color{fg!50!bg}%
              \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
            \fi%
          \else%
            \usebeamercolor{mini frame}%
            %\color{fg!50!bg}%
            \usebeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}%\beamer@minislide%
          \fi%
        }}}\hskip-10cm plus 1fil%
  }\fi\fi%
  \else%
  \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi\ignorespaces
  }
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\section{toto}
   \begin{frame}\frametitle{toto}
      toto 1
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}\frametitle{toto}
      toto 2
   \end{frame}

\section{tata}
\subsection{tutu}
   \begin{frame}\frametitle{tutu}
        tutu
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}\frametitle{tutu}
        tutu 2
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}\frametitle{tutu}
        tutu 3
   \end{frame}

\subsection{titi}
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{titi}
        titi
    \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}\frametitle{titi}
        titi 1
    \end{frame}
    
\section{tata}
\subsection{tutu}
   \begin{frame}\frametitle{tutu}
        tutu
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}\frametitle{tutu}
        tutu 2
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}\frametitle{tutu}
        tutu 3
   \end{frame}

\subsection{titi}
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{titi}
        titi
    \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}\frametitle{titi}
        titi 1
    \end{frame}    

\end{document}


